# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'

Tags: python, django

this error comes up when I try to makemigrations for my python project.
I don't where to look because i have 5 apps with 5 models and views !
does it have relation with attributes with the same name in different models ? 
(i added `related_name='+'` to avoid conflict names).

My django version is : 1.11.3

this is what my terminal returned when i tried to makemigrations :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 323, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 409, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 92, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 149, in state_forwards
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

Comment: Have you actually recently modified all 5 apps and with 5 models and views? If not, the error is probably caused by one of your recent changes. Use your source control to see what changed and post it here. Without that, or the actual models code, it's really hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this was caused by issues with the migrations. The easiest way to fix this, was to reset the migrations for the affected apps using django-reset-migrations: https://github.com/valdergallo/django-reset-migrations

Answer (score 1):

I think something is wrong about your `migrate` files, check them if all exist and implemented. I think some your exist migration files are gone